# How to Hide the row item of Recycleview from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a fragment class which uses Recycleview to show list of Text  and Image. 
How can I access Recycleview row items and set an custom text to any Textview or Hide the Desired Textview from fragment class.

This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="4dp"
android:paddingLeft="2dp"
android:paddingRight="2dp"
android:paddingTop="4dp">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none" />

  <include
    android:id="@+id/include_tag"
    layout="@layout/row_item"/>
 </FrameLayout>
```

and My row item layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res   /android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/flower_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#E91E63"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:text="Sagar Rawal"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/flower_details"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:textColor="#673AB7"
                android:text="This Text need to Be Change "/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

and my Fragment class i s

```
 public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);



    View test1View = view.findViewById(R.id.include_tag);
    mhideText = (TextView) test1View.findViewById(R.id.flower_details);
    mhideText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

return view;
```

But it doesn't work. and Textview is still Visible.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do like this: TextView mhideText; mhideText=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.flower_details);     and then mhideText.setText("This Text is from Row Item")

Comment: what is the difference between your solution and one I atttempted.

Comment: try   View v;
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null); extView mhideText; mhideText=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.flower_details); and then mhideText.setText("This Text is from Row Item") ;   return v;

Comment: `mhideText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.flower_details);` You're supposed to use the `view` object

Comment: I already tried that but it didn't work and I later used this solution from some forums and still it didn't worked for me.

Comment: Are you trying to hide textview that belongs to item of recyclerview? If yes please provide the adapter class as well.

Comment: I am switching from list view to gridview back and forth and on list view I need to show both the textview which I have declared in adapter classs but when in gridview I only need to show the only one textview. so I want to hide from the fragment itself since i have implemented the onclick listener in fragment to switch recycleview.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a custom ViewHolder which should extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder. In your ViewHolder you can link row item and you can access all views from your row layout.
Your custom ViewHolder looks like:

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView textView;
    public MyViewHolder(TextView v) {
        super(v);
        textView = v;
        //Note: To set custom text
        textView.setText("My custom text");

        //Note: To hide TextView remove comment from below line
        //textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
    }
}
```

Above code shows sample ViewHolder as MyViewHolder where you can access your views.
If you are passing parent Layout to MyViewHolder instead of passing TextView then you can find child views using v.findViewById(R.id.xxx)

Your adapter should contain similar code as below:

```
@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
    ...
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}
```

In above code snippet, creating instance of MyViewHolder by passing the view **TextView**. You can pass parent layout *in your case its RelativeLayout* from your row layout.

Use this ViewHolder to take any actions on views like set custom text to TextView or you can hide TextView as per your requirements.

To refer full example you can follow the android documentation or click [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java).

To achieve communication between ViewHolder and fragment you can use Interface.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
rowview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, container, false);
mhideText = (TextView)rowview.findViewById(R.id.flower_details);
mhideText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Mr. Patel it didn't work still Textview is visible.

Comment: Okay than there must be some other problem how about shifting you row_item content to your mainfragment xml file? maybe that should make it work